# Transforming one JAXB Object to another using XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jaxb

I found this question, which helped me a bit, but not enough: [Transform From one JAXB object to another using XSLT template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482785/transform-from-one-jaxb-object-to-another-using-xslt-template)

What I have is this:

- A source JAXB Object
- A class for my target JAXB Object
- A path to the XSLT I want to use to transform my original object to my target object

What I'm trying is this:

```
/**
 * Transforms one JAXB object into another with XSLT
 * @param src The source object to transform
 * @param xsltPath Path to the XSLT file to use for transformation
 * @return The transformed object
 */
public static <T, U> U transformObject(final T src, final String xsltPath) {
    // Transform the JAXB object to another JAXB object with XSLT, it's magic!

    // Marshal the original JAXBObject to a DOMResult
    DOMResult domRes = Marshaller.marshalObject(src);

    // Do something here 
    SAXTransformerFactory tf = (SAXTransformerFactory) TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    StreamSource xsltSrc = new StreamSource(xsltPath);
    TransformerHandler th = tf.newTransformerHandler(xsltSrc);
    th.setResult(domRes);
}
```

At this point, I'm puzzled. How do I obtain my transformed Document? From that point, unmarshalling it back to a JAXB object shouldn't be too hard, I think.

As far as I know, there's no way to do this without marshalling, right?

**UPDATE**

Here is a full working example, using Saxon specifically as my XSLT's are using XSLT 2.0:

```
    /**
     * Transforms one JAXB object into another with an XSLT Source
     * 
     * @param src
     *            The source (JAXB)object to transform
     * @param xsltSrc
     *            Source of the XSLT to use for transformation
     * @return The transformed (JAXB)object
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T, U> U transformObject(final T src, final Source xsltSrc, final Class<U> clazz) {
        try {
            final JAXBSource jxSrc = new JAXBSource(JAXBContext.newInstance(src.getClass()), src);
            final TransformerFactory tf = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
            final Transformer t = tf.newTransformer(xsltSrc);
            final JAXBResult jxRes = new JAXBResult(JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz));
            t.transform(jxSrc, jxRes);
            final U res = (U) jxRes.getResult();

            return res;

        } catch (JAXBException | TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

You can instantiate the xsltSrc through `Source xsltSrc = new StreamSource(new File(...));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `JAXBSource` and `JAXBResult` directly with your transformation.

```
JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(marshaller, src);
JAXBResult result = new JAXBResult(jaxbContext);
transformer.transform(source, result);
Object result = result.getResult();
```

**For More Information**

You can find an example of using JAXB with the `javax.xml.transform` APIs on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/using-jaxb-with-xslt-to-produce-html.html

Comment: That sounds great, how do I do that, exactly?

Comment: @Davio - I added a small example.